# Цитата из Монтеня. Что такое "естественное веление"? а искусственное?

Tags: переводы

> Самыми древними и самыми верными из всех тех предсказаний, которые
>   делались в прошлые времена, были предсказания по полету птиц. Есть ли
>   в нас что-либо похожее или столь замечательное? Правильность и
>   закономерность взмахов их крыльев, по которым судят о предстоящих
>   вещах, – эти замечательные действия должны направляться каким-то
>   изумительным способом, ибо **приписывать эту выдающуюся способность
>   какому-то естественному велению**, не связывая его ни с разумом, ни с
>   пониманием, ни с волей того, кто производит эти движения, – точка
>   зрения, лишенная смысла и несомненно ложная.

Проверяла где могла: *велению*.

Хочу, вестимо, *явлению*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Естественное веление - это природное, оно противопоставлено не искусственному, а личностному. По-моему, слово **веление** здесь на месте.

Энциклопедический словарь (2009) говорит:

> ВЕЛЕ́НИЕ, ВЕЛЕ́НЬЕ, -я; ср. Высок. Приказание, требование или
>   внутреннее побуждение. По велению души, сердца. В. времени, эпохи (то,
>   что диктуется современностью). Как по щучьему велению (неожиданно и
>   самым чудесным образом, как в одноименной сказке). * Веленью Божию, о
>   муза, будь послушна (Пушкин). 
>   Синонимы: волеизъявление, команда, наказ, повеление, приказ,
>   приказание, распоряжение

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/98110

Волеизъявление нам вполне подходит, побуждение тоже. Речь ведь идёт о причинах удивительно разумного поведения птиц. Автор хочет сказать, что их поведение объясняется не просто инстинктом, естественным (природным) побуждением, а именно их волей, там дальше он же говорит  о том, как птицы воспитывают, обучают своё потомство.

Так что это верный перевод, именно **естественное веление:**

> Правильность и закономерность взмахов их крыльев, по которым судят о
>   предстоящих вещах, – эти замечательные действия должны направляться
>   каким-то изумительным способом, ибо приписывать эту выдающуюся
>   способность какому-то естественному велению, не связывая его ни с
>   разумом, ни с пониманием, ни с волей того, кто производит эти
>   движения, – точка зрения, лишенная смысла и несомненно ложная.

Правильность и закономерность взмахов их крыльев - это разумные действия птиц, а не просто природный инстинкт махать крыльями.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, здесь "естественное веление" близко по смыслу современному слову "инстинкт".

И противопоставляется чему-то осмысленному, не стихийному.

Comment: Мишенька! Не "чему-то", а разуму, пониманию и воле птичек. Божиих. Которые суть инстинкт. Ни заботы, ни труда.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим, например, падение воды в водопаде. Я думаю, что Монтень был бы склонен приписывать эту способность воды падать вполне "естественным велениям" (силам "неживой" природы, которые мы бы сейчас назвали "силой тяжести"), "не связывая его ни с разумом, ни с пониманием, ни с волей того, кто производит эти движения".

Вот одно из значения слова **естественный** в словаре Ушакова:

> 3. *только полн.* Совершающийся без постороннего вмешательства, под действием законов природы.

**Хочу, вестимо, явлению...**

Странное желание :)

Comment: А почему мы изучаем "естественный", а не "веление"? **ВЕЛЕНИЕ**: Приказание, требование или внутреннее побуждение. *По велению души, сердца. В. времени, эпохи* (то, что диктуется современностью). *Как по щучьему велению* (неожиданно и самым чудесным образом, как в одноименной сказке). *Веленью Божию, о муза, будь послушна* (Пушкин).

Comment: Разве **веление** вызвало сложность? Я подумал, что "естественное — искусственное" (поскольку антоним не совсем подходящий). А "по воле", которое почти синонимично "по велению", но менее высокопарно? Кстати, в наши времена причины взмахов крыльями большинство сочтёт естественными и совершенно неподходящими для всяких гаданий :)

Answer (score 0):

...приписывать эту выдающуюся способность явлению непромыслительного свойства, не связывая его ни с разумом, ни с пониманием, ни с волей...

...приписывать эту выдающуюся способность явлению непромыслительному, не связывая его ни с разумом, ни с пониманием, ни с волей...

Comment: Я не поняла. Не можем же мы настолько менять источник?! Погуглила - это не цитата... И почему повтор?

Comment: 1. Я объяснил через синоним, попытался т. е., понять и оправдать уместность слова из цитаты. 2. Повтора не вижу. Вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Я не сразу увидела, что не повтор.